# Setting style for Console.log within a string variable?

Tags: javascript, console.log

I am trying to set up a nicer console log output on a javascript script I'm running by using the available styling options.

In this case:

```
s=`Title 1 \n This is some text that follows the first title`;
s=`${s} \n Title 2 \n This is some other text that follows`;
console.log(s);
```

I would like to have an output as:

**Title 1**

This is some text that follows the first title

**Title 2**

This is some other text that follows

But given the examples I've found for styling, I can't find how to do so, as

```
console.log(`%c ${s}`, 'font-weight:bold');
```

would bolden everything inside.

Can I have some advice?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to apply different styles to different parts of the log, you must use multiple `%c` and add multiple style arguments.

```
console.log(`%cTitle 1 \n %cThis is some text that follows the first title`, 'font-weight:bold', 'font-weight: normal');
```

As far as I know, this is the only way to accomplish this.

https://hackernoon.com/styling-logs-in-browser-console-2ec0807dc91a

Answer (score 0):

Just log multiple times then:

```
 console.log(`%c Title 1`, 'font-weight:bold');
 console.log("content");
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is up here for a while, but I was doing performance logging and found this.

```js
var totalTime = 0.634563;
console.log("Widget Modal Performance Update:  Total Operation Time = %c" + totalTime.toFixed(2) + " seconds.", " font-weight: bold; color: #000099");
```

You just have to make sure that %c preceeds the variable in the string addition.